# MPI: writing and read integers to a file

Tags: c, multiprocessing, mpi, openmpi

Just started off with Openmpi. Trying to write and read ints to a file .. code for writing:

the characters getting written to the file are unrecognizable, mostly garbage.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define BUFSIZE 10
#define FIRSTCHAR 1
#define FILENAME "file1.dat"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int i, np, me;
  int buf[BUFSIZE];     /* The buffer to write */
  MPI_File myfile;       /* Shared file */

  /* Initialize MPI */
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &me);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);

  /* Initialize buf with characters. Process 0 uses 'a', process 1 'b', etc. */
  for (i=0; i<BUFSIZE; i++) {
    buf[i] = FIRSTCHAR+(me);
  }

  /* Open the file */
  MPI_File_open (MPI_COMM_WORLD, FILENAME, MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
         MPI_INFO_NULL, &myfile);
  /* Set the file view */
  MPI_File_set_view(myfile, me*BUFSIZE*sizeof(int), MPI_INT, MPI_INT, 
            "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
  /* Write buf to the file */
  MPI_File_write(myfile, buf, BUFSIZE*sizeof(int), MPI_INT, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  /* Close the file */
  MPI_File_close(&myfile);
  MPI_Finalize();
  exit(0);
}
```

dosen't work .. Please help!

Comment: changing paramenters of the api MPI_File_write(myfile, buf, BUFSIZE, MPI_INT, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); dosent help .. let it be noted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The files written are not garbage they are just in binary

if your on linux

first backup your file

```
cp file file2
```

then

try this command to convert from binary to ascii

```
hexdump -v -e '7/4 "%10d "' -e '"\n"' file2
```

also a side note: unless your writing millions of lines to file, you might not even need the mpi_file write /load functions

Comment: hi!! ur brilliant :D works , thanks a lot, also, yeah will be writing a few million lines so using mpi apis

Comment: could u help me with reading , im getting a runtime error, it does read successfully though, from the file

Comment: you could also just do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777828/writing-a-matrix-into-a-single-txt-file-with-mpi

Answer (score 1):

The `int`s are being written to the file in binary mode, i.e. they're not converted to strings and printed like you do screen output using `printf`, instead their memory representation is copied to the file somehow. If you write code to read them from the file (using `MPI_File_read`), it will work properly.

Note that that binary format can be quite tricky to read by yourself, because MPI tries to be cross-platform and probably writes some additional type information, so you should use MPI to read from those files.

Comment: i c, so by writing using mpi api's, i wil be able to read back only if i use mpi_read ?? correct?

Comment: In practice, the output from MPI_File_write is just binary; you could read in all np*BUFSIZE characters with `fread(buf, sizeof(char), np*BUFSIZE, fileh);`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more concise command to view your binary file in ascii
On Linux:
Backup your file, as pyCthon suggested:

```
cp file temp
```

Then, run the following command to print out file as ascii characters:

```
od -c temp
```

If your data happens to be integers:

```
od -i temp
```